# Error launching screen flow from utility bar item

Tags: visual-workflow, utility-bar, variable

I created a screen flow which is launched through a utility item in the utility bar. I tested the flow on a particular custom app which I use, and the flow is able to run fine with no errors. However, when I added the utility item & flow to a separate custom app my team uses, users get this error when clicking the utility item to initiate the flow. Having a hard time figuring out what exactly can be done- not sure if it could be a permissions issue or app issue, since those are the only differences from my testing environment. Any suggestions on what permissions/settings with the app may be throwing this error?

edit: For further context, that particular variable is & should be null when the flow is initiated and it will potentially obtain a value when the user is going through the flow. It is a text variable in the flow w/ use for input & output. Default value for the variable is set to empty string.

edit: I isolated the issue to the app itself. When my user interfaces with the app my team uses, I also get the error.

[image]

Comment: how are you passing the varFullStreetAddress to your flow? If it is the same as in your app then I'd definitely check permissions for whatever field that is being taken from.

Comment: That variable does not have a value when the flow is initiated (other than the 'null string' default value it is provided). It potentially obtains a value through an app called Address Picker Autocomplete which is then used to create an account. The users have access to the Address Picker Autocomplete app, and the field on the Account object the variable is passed to.

I'll double check permission settings to see if I can find anything there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.